# Binding arrow keys using TCL C API

Tags: c, command-line, tcl

I'm using the [TCL C Api](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/contents.html) in my application.

Specifically, I'm using [`Tcl_Main`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/Tcl_Main.html) to create a shell application that runs my commands. This works great, but I'm looking for a way to add typical shell-like functionality (e.g. up arrow to retrieve last command, tab auto-complete, etc.), and I can't figure out how to do it with the TCL C Api.

I've seen solutions that say to wrap the shell in something like GNU readline, but since I'm running a C program that simply calls `Tcl_Main`, I'm not sure how this would be applicable to me.

Any guidance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing your own main loop, call `Tcl_MainLoop(yourImplFunc);` before `Tcl_Main()` to plug that in. That's literally what it's there for.

Your main loop will need to manipulate the terminal, and Tcl doesn't itself provide any mechanism for that before Tcl 8.7 (but extensions may do so). The main thing is you need to get the file descriptor for stdin (see `Tcl_GetChannelHandle`) and pass that in to `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()` to put the terminal into raw mode. Once in raw mode, you can see things like the arrow keys, but a down side of that is you have to do all the processing. That's why people use the readline library.

Comment: I'm sorry this is just a sketch of what you need to do, but it's quite a lot of work!